# Rails - Export CSV not working as expected (undefined method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I am doing a CSV Export in Rails App.
The data is returned as a JSON array from the backend API. 
But now I am getting error as `"undefined method  'to_csv' for #Hash:0x007f149a5ff978"` in the export_data method.

I have included `require "csv"` in the config/application.rb file, and did server restarts.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

**index.html.erb**

```
<a href="usage_metrics/export_data.csv"><button class="btn btn-default">Export to CSV</button></a>
```

**usage_controller(front end)**

```
      def export_data
        rest_resource = RestClient::Resource.new( ENV['USAGE_METRICS_API'] + '/get_events_data', :verify_ssl => false )
        request = rest_resource.get  :Authorization => cookies.signed[:remember_token], :content_type => 'application/json'
        @events_data = JSON.parse(request)


        respond_to do |format|
             format.html
             format.csv { send_data @events_data.to_csv }
        end
      end   


      def self.to_csv
        CSV.generate do |csv|
          csv << column_names
          all.each do |event|
            csv << event.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
          end
        end
      end
```

Comment: `all.each` ? What is all?

Comment: Your `self.to_csv` method is meant to be included on a model, not in a controller. Even if you were to call it correctly, it's not suitable for the JSON object that you're actually working with. You will need to write a custom serialization that turns your `@events_data` JSON object into a CSV.

Comment: For my app, there is no model logic in the front end, it should come from backend.

Answer (score 0):

Your self.to_csv method doesn't make sense in the controller

You need to move to_csv to you model which will serialize the data into a csv

follow this tutorial to implement this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel